# ASP Net core Https Request

Tags: https, debian, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with my ASP .Net Core MVC application deployed on a Debian Environment.

Each time i try to make a **HTTPS** request, the application is killed and I have to restart it.

Did someone already have this problem ?

For information, a simple wget on the same URL is working in SSH.

Comment: Could it be the code in your request? Setup a simple “hellos world” html page and see if that crashes your application.

Comment: No its perfectly working for http request, i just have the problem when the website i want to request is https

Comment: Any exceptions/errors raised by your apps?

Comment: No i dont get anny error or exception